# Implementing a JWT Auth Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, jwt

I am trying to implement an RSA JWT authentication service. I have followed other posts on here, but I am unsure if the service I have created is truly secure.

Let me lay out the flow:

1. Client hits auth service and is authenticated
2. Create RSA Public/Private keys.
3. Generate JWT signing with Private key.
4. Respond to user with JWT along with the Public key that was generated previously
5. Client holds JWT
6. Client sends JWT and Public key in HTTP Header to separate protected service.
7. Protected service uses Public key to decrypt the JWT

**My concerns are:**

1. If the HTTP request has all the information required to decrypt the JWT then does this not mean that anyone could use this to then access the protected service?
2. My understanding of RSA encryption is that 2 parties generate their own Public/Private keys. They swap Public keys. One uses the other's Public key to encrypt, which can only be decrypted by the corresponding Private key. That means that only the correct client can read the information. **This is not what happens in this situation**

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear in JWT, a public key is what allows you to decrypt the token back to data and private key is what allows you to decrypt as well as encrypt i.e. generate JWT from data.

So the idea of using JWT is that you don't need public/private key from the client every time. You keep those in your back-end. You just provide the JWT to the client, once the client is authenticated. Most of the times, this JWT is stored in client's session (or cookie). The client then sends that JWT every time with requests that require authentication. The server has the public/private keys to decrypt the JWT and verify if the request is authentic.

This is just a very basic working but I hope it helps clear things.

Comment: Thank you. A lot of good points there. Issue is that the backend does not have public/private, as this is a distributed system. i.e. the JWT is created in the Authentication Service, and then we send this JWT in Cookies to other services. Therefore these other services need to be passed the key to decrypt the JWT

Comment: So you don't need these keys in every service. You can create an end-point in your auth service that accepts JWT as a param and returns the result of token validation. This involves service to service communication and you can use whatever communication (orchestration or choreographed) mean you have in place to facilitate this. All of your services can leverage your Auth service for such tasks.

Comment: Sorry, was this answer helpful?